# MacBook Air MacOS Mojava (10.14.6) crashes or restarts with python turtle module

Tags: python, macos, python-idle

MacBook Air MacOS Mojava (10.14.6) crashes when python turtle module is executed using python Python 3.9.0 (v3.9.0:9cf6752276)

```
from turtle import Turtle
laura = Turtle()
laura.color('red')
laura.shape('turtle')
```

When I execute the code above, a small python launcher appears and then, my MacBook either restarts, freezes until I restart it using the power button or displays a white screen with black lines (static screen) before restarting. I use IDLE 3.9 to type up the code, however when I run it using python launcher, it crashes as soon as laura = Turtle() is executed. However on another admin on the same MacBook, it does not crash or restart but works successfully. Neither does my Mac restart when I execute the same code from Trinket.

I have also updated to python 3.9.1 `(Python 3.9.1 (v3.9.1:1e5d33e9b9, Dec  7 2020, 12:10:52))  with IDLE 3.9.1` as well as ran the file from terminal but still face the same issue.

```
Terminal: python3 file.py
Mac restarts 
message on termial:  e.g([Restored Feb 18, 2021 at 10:44:28 AM])
```

Please advice me what to do.

Thank you.

Comment: That sounds...rather severe, actually. I know that some configurations of Python, Tkinter and macOS can result in a Python process crash, but nothing should be capable of crashing your whole computer. A few possibilities: a buggy graphics driver, flaky hardware, or a kernel extension in need of an update; however, none of those immediately suggest a problem which would be specific to one user account.

Comment: If macOS crashes and reboots, it'll usually show a message saying "Your computer restarted because of a problem" after rebooting. In that message, the report button will pop up a large dialog box with a crash report - that report might be useful in diagnosing the problem. Post that if you're able.

Comment: I have Macbook Air, updated Mohave, 3.9.1.  I ran import and Screen() in both Terminal REPL and IDLE Shell and both work fine.  IDLE should have nothing to do with your problem as it executes your code in a separate process with no GUI.

Comment: Exactly why I am confused. Since a program shouldn't crash the entire laptop especially when it works perfectly for another user on the same MacBook. however I posted this issue on Apple community too and this is what I got https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252468071?answerId=254652742022#254652742022.    It worked when I executed  the mentioned python script.(wrote in Atom and executed using Terminal). As even after updating to Big Sur I faced the exact same issue.